# IOS 7 UISegmentControl set tint color not working

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

IOS 7 UISegmentControl set tint color not working.
How am I going to solve it?

Here is my code for adding:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"YES",@"NO", nil]];

[segmentControl setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

but the color only appear at border, i want it to color whole background.

As I referred from the Library,

```
@property(nonatomic) UISegmentedControlStyle segmentedControlStyle NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "The segmentedControlStyle property no longer has any effect");*
```

Comment: iOS7 is governed by Apple's non-disclosure agreement.  Question will likely be closed.

Comment: @Jeremy Stackoverflow will not enforce the NDA: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors

Comment: You are correct.  The readers will.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, UISegmentcontrol setTintColor is available in IOS6 and it worked fine in my app, but now i upgrade to IOS7 beta version it act like bit weird the color run out and only appear at border. I just want it to show like what it showing in IOS6.

Comment: I have been changed my code, is it okay for reviewing?

Comment: Thats the appearance of the SegmentedControl in ios7 unfortunately. I think Apple are trying to unify the look of controls between apps.

Comment: I found the answer here, set the subviews instead..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773400/segmented-control-tintcolor-in-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

The UISegmentedControl relates to the tint color of the UINavigationBar.
If you change the color, the tint color of the UISegmentedControl will change accordingly.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]  setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score -4):

I think you may want:

[segmentControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

Comment: No that's different to the tint colour -1