# How do I use iOS7 controls without upgrading your nib files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

At this point in time I'd like to keep my code compatible with Xcode 4, therefore I don't want to upgrade my nib files.

However, I can't change the UISegmentedControl control tint colour and use the new iOS7 version of the control without upgrading the nib file.

I've seen ..

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@Yes forKey@"UIUseLegacyUID"]
```

Which will keep iOS6 layout, I'm not sure if there is an future version or whether this would help?

Comment: I've found the answer here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773400/segmented-control-tintcolor-in-ios-6

Comment: Fascinating. This looks like a bug to me. Could you submit a bug report to Apple about this?

Comment: I've read that apple are trying to standardise controls across views. However, this fix was originally for iOS5, as it doesn't work on iOS6. So I think they may have changed how this is supposed to work in the new control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode 5, you can change your XIB to use the property of Xcode 4 and iOS 6.

By default you have:

[image]

But, you can change the property for Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this, but doing so doesn't allow me access to the iOS7 version of the segmented control.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tint color in the code like this:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = ...;
// For backwards compatibility
if ([segmentedControl respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)])
{
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work on iOS7 unless you use the upgraded nib control.

Answer (score 0):

You can set different segment image and color for each segment. For color you may use:

```
//get the subviews of the segmentedcontrol

NSArray *arri = [segmentedControl subviews];

//change the color of every subview(segment) you have

[[arri objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[arri objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```